# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x}{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, x> 0, y > 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to solve this limit, given that x >0 and y > 0.

It was suggested to me that this can be solved as:

$\lim_{r\to0} r{\cot{\theta}}$

And since x > 0 and y > 0, then $\cot{\theta}$ cannot be infinity and r is zero therefore the limit is zero, but I am not convinced since the same logic can be applied to r.

Comment: A (perhaps) invalid, purely intuitive argument is that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ which is measuring distance from the origin is neutral in that it does not affect the variability of $\frac{x}{y}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by polar coordinates we obtain

$$\frac{x}{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =r\cot \theta $$

but we can't conclude since $\cot \theta$ is not bounded.

Indeed by $x=y=t\to 0^+$ we obtain

$$\frac{x}{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \sqrt 2 t \to 0$$

but by $x=t\to 0^+$ and $y=t^2\to 0^+$ we obtain

$$\frac{x}{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{t}{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+t^4}}=\sqrt{1+t^2} \to1$$

Comment: Does this mean that the limit does not exist since we get 2 answers with different results 0 and 1?

Comment: @SherifElmetainy Yes exactly!

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.